# Eclipse plugin development editor annotate selected content

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, editor

I want to implement a eclipse plugin to allow use to highlight the selected content via context menu. That is, user first select a text segment, with the context menu, user can highlight this part with colors.
Current problem is I can implement the context menu and get selected part. How can I highlight that part with a color. Is that possible without implementing sourceviewer and annotation model?

Comment: Is this an editor you are writing or an existing editor?

Comment: `SourceViewerDecorationSupport` deals with annotations and can draw them in various styles.